# Why I get a pom that can be build by jdk8, 10, 11, 12, but only not jdk9?

Tags: java, maven, compiler-errors, java-9

It's amazing.

I don't understand why but it really happens.

you can get build report from https://travis-ci.org/cyanpotion/cyan_potion/builds/542756143

you can get codes there too.

Sorry but I cannot put the pom here, it is just too large that stack over flow refused it.

And, if things like it often happens, or I'm just being unlucky this time?

---

```
[DEBUG] incrementalBuildHelper#beforeRebuildExecution
[INFO] Compiling 88 source files to D:\workspace\cyan_potion\src\base\target\classes
[DEBUG] incrementalBuildHelper#afterRebuildExecution
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  12.809 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-06-07T20:20:06+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project cyan_potion_base: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project cyan_potion_base: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I opened -e -X on my local machine, and this is where it started the error.

---

I know it might be a really silly question.

If you know how to solve it, please tell me where I went wrong after/before you negate the question. Thanks sincerely.

Comment: Did you try it on your local machine? What message besides "compilation failed" do you get?

Comment: Can you update to the latest version of [maven-compiler-plugin](https://search.maven.org/search?q=maven-compiler-plugin) and re-run the builds? I suspect it could be some Maven issue.

Comment: updated and still fails on local. trying in https://travis-ci.org/cyanpotion/cyan_potion/builds/542786371

Comment: Looking at the logs ([line 718](https://travis-ci.org/cyanpotion/cyan_potion/jobs/542786373#L718)), I see it still uses version 3.1:
`[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ cyan_potion_base ---`

Comment: my mistake. it must begins before I deploy the parent pom...will restart it.

Comment: @Boris I increased version number to force travis-ci refresh.but, still fails. https://travis-ci.org/cyanpotion/cyan_potion/builds/542803525

Comment: But now we get [more info](https://travis-ci.org/cyanpotion/cyan_potion/jobs/542803526#L760) from the plugin:
`java.lang.NullPointerException
 at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.JarFileSystem.getVersionMap(JarFileSystem.java:137)`
Apparently it's a known Java 9 bug [JDK-8193802](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8193802).

Comment: @Boris Thanks a lot! I will learn about how to avoid it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194606/discussion-between-boris-and-xenoamess).

Comment: Given Java 9 is EOL and superseded, why do you continue to use Java 9?

Comment: First I recommend to upgrade the plugins your are using to the most recent ones...than check running on JDK11+12 on a local machine if this works go to travis....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I just abandoned jdk 9.

I don't want to figure out which part of jdk 9 have bug or how to let maven put some useless files into jars just for pushing jdk9 to build it, no any more.

Maybe I shall make this decision earlier, thus I can enjoy a good night with some good movies or board games with friends...

Anyway thanks for your help guys...